# My program does not stop and returns the same answer

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

Program that asks the user to guess generated number between 1 and 9. If player guessed too low, too high or equal there will be a message saying so. Program only finish when player types 'exit'.

I've created three functions.

```
import random

#function that creates a random number in between 1 and 9 inclusive
def number_generation():
  computer_number=random.randint(1,9)
  return computer_number
print(number_generation())

#function that asks the player to input number between 1 and 9
def player_number():
  player_num=input('Digit your guess between 1 and 9\n')
  return player_num

def guessing_game():
  w_answers=0
  r_answers=0
  cpu_guess=int(number_generation())
  player_guess=player_number()
  while player_guess!='exit':
    if int(player_guess)>cpu_guess:
      print('You have guessed to high')
      w_answers+=1
    elif int(player_guess)<cpu_guess:
      print('You have guessed to low')
      w_answers+=1
    else:
      print('You have guessed the correct number')
      r_answers+=1
  return w_answers,r_answers
print(guessing_game())
```

It prints forever your guess is too low..

Comment: You never ask for another `player_input`

Comment: What have you already tried, to debug this?

Comment: i ask for player input in function

Comment: i've tried many thing like calling function outside while,etc

Comment: @Luismaia1994, ask for user input inside loop, because you need to keep on asking.

Comment: Yes, but you only call the function once before going into the while loop, you don't call it while in the loop so `player_input` never changes.

Comment: in the while loop now i wrote player_answer=player_number() but now it asks me two times in a row for input

Comment: between if i input the same number generated it says my number is too low

Comment: That first number printed is not the number randomly generated. Remove the first print. You are not getting how your code works. Go through your code from top to bottom.

Comment: austin i only printed that number to next input a number low or high and see if that number is lower or higher than the generated in order to validate the results

Comment: Print `cpu_guess` to know what randomly generated number is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments:

- Move the player guess inside the while loop.
- I would suggest a `while True` loop with a call to  `exit()` on typing `exit`

```
import random

#function that creates a random number in between 1 and 9 inclusive
def number_generation():
    return random.randint(1,9)

#function that asks the player to input number between 1 and 9
def player_number():
    player_num=input('Digit your guess between 1 and 9\n')
    return player_num

def guessing_game():
    w_answers=0
    r_answers=0

    #CPU guess outside the loop
    cpu_guess = int(number_generation())

    #While true loop
    while True:
        #Make the player guess inside
        player_guess = player_number()

        #If exit is typed, exit
        if player_guess.lower() == 'exit':
            break
        #Else compare the guesses
        if int(player_guess)>cpu_guess:
            print('You have guessed to high')
            w_answers+=1
        elif int(player_guess)<cpu_guess:
            print('You have guessed to low')
            w_answers+=1
        else:
            print('You have guessed the correct number')
            r_answers+=1
    return w_answers,r_answers

print(guessing_game())
```

A run might look like

```
Digit your guess between 1 and 9
4
You have guessed the correct number
Digit your guess between 1 and 9
2
You have guessed to low
Digit your guess between 1 and 9
6
You have guessed to high
Digit your guess between 1 and 9
8
You have guessed to high
Digit your guess between 1 and 9
exit
(3, 1)
```